# When to use Mock or Fake or Overrides?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, tdd

Lets say I have the below method called DoSomething.

When writing unit tests how do I know whether to use a Fake, Mock or Override approach and why is one better than the other?

```
public List<MyClass> DoSomething()
{
  List<MyClass> data = GetData();

  if (data.Count == 0)
    return new List<MyClass>();

  data = GetFormattedData(data);

  if (data.Count == 0)
    return new List<MyClass>();

  return data;
}

[Test]
public void DoSomething_NoData_ReturnsEmptyList()
{
  //Change method parameters to pass in IDataProvider that exposes GetData method
  //Create FakeProvider class implementing IDataProvider
  //Ensure FakeProvider.GetData returns no data

  //Create FakeClass that inherits class from DoSomething class
  //Make FakeClass.GetData return no data
  //When DoSomething is called in the test it will call the parent class

  //Create Mock of class that DoSomething/GetData/GetFormattedData is in
  //Tell mock to make sure GetData returns empty list
  //Call DoSomething in test
}

[Test]
public void DoSomething_NoFormattedData_ReturnsEmptyList()
{
   //Same possibilities exist as above
}
```

Comment: What does `GetData()` do? Also, `DoSomething` is a method, not a class.

Comment: Never said it was a class. GetData goes off to a database and returns List<MyClass>

Comment: Shouldn't you test as well what happens when GetData() returns null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you could supply your function with the data so that the function signature would be `public List<MyClass> DoSomething(List<MyClass data)` Then your function would only have a single responsibility and that would be to format the data.

If you still want to do the data fetch withing your function and you will be accessing a database or external service I would use dependency injection and mocking to test the function.

Generally it is good to avoid dependencies if possible. It all depends of course, if you don't do any other data fetching in your class then it's just a matter of how far down you will send your dependency.

Comment: The same question applies to the GetFormattedData though. This isn't using a database, this is just taking in List<MyClass> and doing some logic on it. How do I test for that method returning an empty list?

Comment: If the format data is a private for that class then you will never get to that state since you check if you get a result from the GetData function. If you don't you return. So it should not be a case, what you are interested in is how the function behaves, and the result will be that if it doesn't get any data it returns an empty list. It doesn't matter if it's the FormatData or DoSomething() that makes the return. When testing you don't want the test to break if you change the implementation as long as the result for the same input stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly is *fake* approach different from *override* one? In both cases you'll most likely end up having to create new class inheriting from the one you want to test.

Anyways, I don't see much differences to be honest, and IMO you got two options:

- mocking (which will require bit redesigning and dependency injection)
- overriding (known as *extract and override*)

Both are valid and none is *way better than the other*. Problem with *extract and override* is that you'll need extra types/files. That of course means more stuff to manage by hand - if that can be avoided, it should be. Personally, I'd go with this one **only** when existing mocking frameworks can't handle your scenario.

Major advantage of mocking/injection technique is that it forces you to do better design - having [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles in mind and overral writing more testable/managable code. Not to mention, there're many frameworks supporting this technique ([Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/), [RhinoMocks](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-mocks), [FakeItEasy](http://code.google.com/p/fakeiteasy/) - to name the most popular ones).